# Twitterの様な投稿フォームを再現するには

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

railsもしくはbootstrapのライブラリを用いて、

[image]

このようにツイッターの新規投稿ボタン？を押すと画面が遷移せず、背景が暗くなり、フォームが
出てくる。という機能をつけたいのですが、そういったライブラリはあるのでしょうか？
もしあるのなら何と調べればいいのかご教授願いたいですm（__）m

Answer (score 1):

[Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) をベースにフォームやボタンを追加すると、同じような画面を実装できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！リンクまで張っていただき恐縮です！